# How to create as many objects as the number of files/objects in php

Tags: php, html, html5-filesystem

I have to make a "homepage" type .php page, which contains objects depending on the number of files in a certain folder. The following code is example how the objects should look like, I have arranged them in a table for easier allignment.

```css
.index_poster {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: auto;

    width: 16em;
    height: 9em;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 2em rgb(180,180,180);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2em rgb(180,180,180);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2em rgb(180,180,180);
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr align="center"><td align="center">
              <div>
                  <script type="text/javascript">
                      function actualNextSibling(el) {    // needed to smooth out default firefox/IE behavior
                          do { el = el.nextSibling } while (el && el.nodeType !== 1);
                              return el; 
                      }
                  </script>
                  
                  <div onclick="actualNextSibling(this).style.display='block'; this.style.display='none'">
                      <img class="index_poster" src="posters/BatmanJoker1.jpg" style="cursor: pointer" />
                  </div>
                  
                  <div style="display: none">
                      <video class="index_poster" controls>
                          <source src="videos/BatmanJoker1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                          <source src="" type="video/ogg">
                          <source src="" type="video/webm">
                          Your browser does not support the video tag or the file format of this video.
                      </video>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div>
                  <form action="https://www.google.com">
                      <input type="submit" class="button" value="EDIT SUBTITLES">
                  </form>
              </div>
              <br><br>
          </td>

          <td align="center">
              <div>
                  <script type="text/javascript">
                      function actualNextSibling(el) {    // needed to smooth out default firefox/IE behavior
                          do { el = el.nextSibling } while (el && el.nodeType !== 1);
                              return el; 
                      }
                  </script>
                  
                  <div onclick="actualNextSibling(this).style.display='block'; this.style.display='none'">
                      <img class="index_poster" src="posters/BatmanJoker2.jpg" style="cursor: pointer" />
                  </div>
                  
                  <div style="display: none">
                      <video class="index_poster" controls>
                          <source src="videos/BatmanJoker2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                          <source src="" type="video/ogg">
                          <source src="" type="video/webm">
                          Your browser does not support the video tag or the file format of this video.
                      </video>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div>
                  <form action="https://www.google.com">
                      <input type="submit" class="button" value="EDIT SUBTITLES">
                  </form>
              </div>
              <br><br>
          </td></tr><table>
```

My question is how do I create as much objects as the files in /videos/ and /posters/ folders.
I have read some information on how to count files in a .php FileSystem, but I don't seem to find a solution or a similar question.

Comment: After you count the files you just repeat the element(s) you want repeated the same number of times (for, foreach, while)

Comment: @JimL I am pretty new, do you mind if I ask you to help me with a code?

Comment: What do you need help with?

Comment: @JimL I can count the number of files, I need the to know how to "repeat" the elements with for/while/foreach, because I have a "table" arrangement and I am not sure exactly how to do it.

Comment: Just wrap the part(s) you want to repeat in `for($i = 0; $i < count($elements); $i++) { /* this is repeated */ }`